# Here's a fun question, what would happen if Venus was thrown off in a highly elliptical orbit?

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics, atmospheric-science, meteorology

I'd like to know what would happen if Venus was flung into a highly eccentric orbit like Sedna (except maybe with its current perihelion) with an orbital period measured in thousands of years by a freak object such as a rogue planet. I guess you could look at the changes on a timescale and maybe even different scenarios based on the kind of object that would give it such a boost. I think this would be quite interesting considering the CO2 atmosphere of Venus and its earth-like mass. Like how would its seasons be? What would happen to that CO2 at those ridiculous distances from the sun? How long would its atmosphere be able to retain the atmosphere and how long would it take for it to cool down? Just some of the questions I can think of regarding this scenario.

Comment: Seems to be a pretty open-ended question, which is not well suited to a question and answer forum like Physics SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a fairly broad [*What if ____ happened*](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) type question.

Comment: [Worlds in Collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worlds_in_Collision)

Comment: Closer to Astronomy stack than here but open ended and non specific for there as well.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to know what would happen if Venus was flung into a highly
>   eccentric orbit like Sedna (except maybe with its current perihelion)
>   with an orbital period measured in thousands of years.

It's kind of a weird question but the first thing to consider is whether the orbit crosses any other planetary orbits, cause if it does, the biggest effect of this event could be a collision or some significant planetary adjustment.   In 3 dimensions, however, it's possible to have a planet pass both closer and further from the sun than another object but not cross orbits.   Pluto and Neptune's orbits don't cross, but it's hard to express that in 2 dimensions.   It looks like the cross but they don't.

[image]

Like the mythical planet X, if this was to happen suddenly, Venus would send Kuiper belt and Oort Cloud objects in all directions and the 7 remaining planets get more frequent bombardment with each pass Venus makes.  Not late heavy bombardment levels, but perhaps enough to threaten life on earth.   Over enough time, Venus would clear much of it's orbital path, but initially the outer objects that Venus passes close to would get stirred up a fair bit and some would get sent in towards the sun and planets.

It's also possible that Venus would capture a moon every so often.

If it crossed close enough to one or more of the planets, which would largely depend on it's angel of inclination it could do quite a bit of damage, perhaps destabilizing a 2nd planet or measurably changing the orbit of our moon if it passes too close to the Earth.

But I suspect your question was more about planet weather and temperature than orbital mechanics, so, moving on.

> Like how would its seasons be?

Seasons change with every year.   If you have a planet with a very elliptical orbit that passes close to the sun for only a few months, spends maybe a couple years inside the frost line and spends the bulk if it's time (like 98% of it's 10,000 year orbit) more distant than Uranus, you basically have a planet that freezes solid and has virtually no atmosphere for 9,000-9,500 years, has a very thin Pluto to Mars like atmosphere for maybe a few hundred years and has a brief warm summer with relatively rapid thawing of the frozen atmosphere, followed by re-freezing.   Wash, Rince, Repeat.

> What would happen to that CO2 at those ridiculous distances from the
>   sun?

it would freeze.   CO2 Freezes at 194K, so once Venus was more than 4 or 5 AU from the sun, the freezing should commence pretty quickly.

> How long would its atmosphere be able to retain the atmosphere and how
>   long would it take for it to cool down?

That would take some time.   The first trip Venus took out of the solar system it would take much longer to cool down than later trips.   The later trips, Venus wouldn't have enough time to heat up all that much.    Venus is very reflective, so it might not even get that warm, even as it passes as close as 60 million miles to the sun.   Most of Venus' heat is trapped heat, but spending 10,000 years in deep space would cool down Venus a lot.

here's a [similar article](http://www.popsci.com/node/204957) on Earth and [another](http://curious.astro.cornell.edu/our-solar-system/39-our-solar-system/the-earth/other-catastrophes/61-how-long-could-life-on-earth-survive-if-the-sun-stopped-shining-beginner), note, the estimates differ pretty significantly.

Obviously Venus traps heat more efficiently and it's much hotter at the surface than Earth, so it would take several times longer for Venus to cool down and freeze.  Earth probably sees frozen ocean cover within a few months, so a 5,000 year journey to it's furthest point, before it moves back in would be more than long enough for Venus to freeze and basically turn into a big Pluto.   I don't want to guess how long, cause I might guess badly, but for the surface of Venus to cool and freeze when it's far from the sun, I don['t know, 25 years, 50, 100?  Something like that.   The inside of Venus would stay hot much longer, but the inside of planets doesn't heat the surface very much.   On Earth, I think our hot core gives us only about 5 degrees of surface temperature warming.   Not nearly enough to keep things from freezing.   Given enough time, and I think, much much less than 10,000 years, Venus would have a frozen icy surface in your wacky scenario.